# The variable in the match statement is not working properly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This code gives me the PERMISSION_DENIED if i try to query the document

```
match /tasks/{task}{
  allow read, write: if task in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.members;
}
```

and, if i try the following code, it works

```
match /tasks/{task}{
  allow read, write: if "1jKpWhAqIzY0TspshKao" in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.members;
}
```

the string `"1jKpWhAqIzY0TspshKao"` is name/id of the document

**/tasks/{taskid}**

```
{
  owner: "4v8Bz4dsvtg4jG3l8nih71MRwy49",
  taskId: "1jKpWhAqIzY0TspshKao",
  title: "Some task"
}
```

**/users/{userid}**

```
{
  email: "email@gmail.com",
  members: {
    "1jKpWhAqIzY0TspshKao", "EKwNgHukewtachrTfDMk" ...
  }
  username: "name"
}
```

I used the following code to query a document for the both rules

```
db.collection("tasks").get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
  ...
}
```

what's wrong with that first code?

Comment: What is the code that's accessing the document?  What are the exact contents of the document?  Without seeing all the relevant details, we can't track what's going on here.

Comment: Hi, @Doug Stevenson thank you for the response. I corrected my question please 
have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to get all the tasks in the `tasks` collection.  But it seems that you intend for your security rule to filter the tasks based on the evaluation of the rules.  This isn't how security rules works.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules):

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. To save you time and
>   resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential
>   result set instead of the actual field values for all of your
>   documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the
>   client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.

So, probably what's happening is the query for the current user is failing on at least one of the documents, which is causing the entire query to fail.  Your query needs to be specific about indicating which documents it knows it should have access to, or, you need to restructure your data to suit your intended query.